# How to return next() and prev() in a parameter?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating a simple slider that has 2 buttons with almost the same code. The only difference would be `next()` and `prev()`. So I use a parameter (`direction`) for this.

In this case I get the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Why?

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // Navi
    function navi(direction) {
      if ($('.slider').find('.active').direction.length != 0) {
        $('.slider')
          .find('.active')
          .removeClass('active')
          .direction
          .addClass('active');   
       }
     }

    $('.next').on('click', function() {
    navi('next()');
  });

  $('.back').on('click', function() {
    navi('prev()');
  });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/n339tzff/3/

Comment: @guest271314 the parameter. It should be either `next()` or `prev()`.

Comment: Did you look at your error? `$('.slider').find('.active')` has no `direction` attribute.

Comment: You have not sending value for the variable of direction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass the string without parenthesis, use bracket notation

```
$('.next').on('click', function() {
    navi('next');
});
```

```
if ($('.slider').find('.active')[direction]().length != 0)
```

Comment: @Alexandru-IonutMihai _"That is not enought"_ ? Not enough for what?

Comment: @Alexandru-IonutMihai Yes it is. OP should be able to gather that `"prev"` needs to be passed at `$('.back').on('click', function() {
    navi('prev');
  });` and `[direction]()` used at `.removeClass('active')
          [direction]()
          .addClass('active')`, as indicated by text at Answer

Comment: Thank you for your answer but now I get the error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token [

Comment: @RezaSaadati At which line? No errors are logged at jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/n339tzff/5/

Comment: Oh now I see! In your code there is no dot (`.`) needed. If I remove the dot before `[direction]()`, then it works! I don't understand why ... can you explain it to me please?

Comment: Methods and properties and just syntax sugar for an array of properties.  So `x.i=1` is the same as `x["i"]=1`.  So `arrayOfJqueryObjects["method"]()` is the same as `arrayOfJqueryObjects.method()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass a string into a function and expect it to act as executable code (unless you resort to `new Function()` or `eval()`, neither of which you should do). But, you can write a simple `if/them` that executes the right command based on string input:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

      // Navi
      function navi(direction) {
        // You need this no matter what the direction is:
        var $active = $('.slider').find('.active');
        if(direction === "next" && $active.next().length === 1) {
            $active.removeClass('active');
            $active.next().addClass('active');;
        } else if(direction == "prev" && $active.prev().length === 1) {
            $active.removeClass('active');
            $active.removeClass(".active").prev().addClass('active');   
        }

      }

      $('.next').on('click', function() { navi('next'); });
      $('.back').on('click', function() { navi('prev'); });

    });
```

```css
.slider {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
}
.slider img { 
  float: left; 
  display: none;
}
.active {
  display: block !important;
}
.next, .back {
  width: 100px; 
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: skyblue;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slider">
  <img src="http://keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/jcrop/demos/demo_files/image1.jpg" alt="" class="active">
  <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_lights.jpg" alt="">
  <img src="http://keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/jcrop/demos/demo_files/image2.jpg" alt="">
  <img src="http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphiclarge/a_london_cityscape_515129.jpg" alt="">
  <img src="https://image.jimcdn.com/app/cms/image/transf/dimension=1920x400:format=jpg/path/s86d6d6c688ca86fa/image/ie4265a3cd27b2997/version/1451246087/image.jpg" alt="">
</div>
<div class="back">Back</div>
<div class="next">Next</div>
```

Comment: @guest271314 Yup. Thanks!

Comment: What is happened when we reach the last image and click next ?

Comment: @Alexandru-IonutMihai Nothing, because there is an `if/then` that is checking for that.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a solution like this;

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.next').click(function(){
      var x =  $('.active'); //grab active class because we will delete it soon
       $('.active').removeClass('active'); //now remove active class
      if($(x).next('img').length < 1){ //check if it is the last img element
         $('img').eq(0).addClass('active'); //if yes return to first img
      } else {
      $(x).next('img').addClass('active'); //else go on.
      }
    });
  $('.back').click(function(){
      var x =  $('.active');
       $('.active').removeClass('active');
     if($(x).prev('img').length < 1){
        $('img').eq(4).addClass('active');
     } else {
      $(x).prev('img').addClass('active');
     }
    });
});
```

In this script You are able to slide next img or prev image with nav buttons and your loop will be infinite.

here is a [**DEMO**](http://cr8code.co/editor.php?workid=3c1646cd30170c35c03d1d9b0cfe5c57):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('.next').click(function(){
      var x =  $('.active');
       $('.active').removeClass('active');
      if($(x).next('img').length < 1){
         $('img').eq(0).addClass('active');
      } else {
      $(x).next('img').addClass('active');
      }
    });
  $('.back').click(function(){
      var x =  $('.active');
       $('.active').removeClass('active');
     if($(x).prev('img').length < 1){
        $('img').eq(4).addClass('active');
     } else {
      $(x).prev('img').addClass('active');
     }
    });
});
```

```css
.slider {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
}
.slider img { 
  float: left; 
  display: none;
}
.active {
  display: block !important;
}
.next, .back {
  width: 100px; 
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: skyblue;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slider">
  <img src="http://keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/jcrop/demos/demo_files/image1.jpg" alt="" class="active">
  <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_lights.jpg" alt="">
  <img src="http://keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/jcrop/demos/demo_files/image2.jpg" alt="">
  <img src="http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphiclarge/a_london_cityscape_515129.jpg" alt="">
  <img src="https://image.jimcdn.com/app/cms/image/transf/dimension=1920x400:format=jpg/path/s86d6d6c688ca86fa/image/ie4265a3cd27b2997/version/1451246087/image.jpg" alt="">
</div>
<div class="back">Back</div>
<div class="next">Next</div>
```

Comment: Please don't link to code at 3rd party sites as those links can become stale/dead over time and then your answer won't be accessible. Also, there are opportunities in your code to DRY.

Comment: That was why I did share the js code as well which was the answer. If the link dies than there still would be answer.

Comment: Yes, but why not just post a code snippet here and then there is no issue, ever?

Comment: Because i created the code in that playground and didnt want to spend extra efford, also to make it a valid answer i posted the js code into the answer.  No offense thank you for editing the answer.